# Styling links like regular text in print view

Tags: html, css

I have a page I want to print that has a bunch of content with links.

Is there a way to style the links using css so the link titles look like normal text?

I want to have my link that normally looks like:
[Google](http://www.google.com)
look like normal text without a hyperlink:
Google

Answer (score 3):

Add an other css file like this:

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

When you print it will call this css file, not the regular one for `media="screen"`

Comment: I was already calling a css sheet meant for printing. When I specified media="print" it stripped ALL the formatting. There was nothing specified before.

Comment: Don't strip all of it, specify what you want the links to look like - all browsers will style links by default (blue + underline).

Comment: I meant that specifying media="print" seems to take all the formatting of everything away.

Comment: That would happen indeed if you add an empty CSS file for print, but shouldn't happen if you actually have some CSS declarations in it... CSS file for print is not for overruling screen CSS, it's completely separate. Also, sure you haven't made any typos?

Comment: @ptriek Do I have to specify something in the CSS sheet itself?

Comment: The problem(I think) with this solution is that I have already gotten myself a css sheet for printing. (I say this to clarify why the answer probably wont be the accepted one even though it has the most votes. I have a somewhat working answer, but it involves the css itself, not adding a css sheet)

Comment: But why would you have a printed css stylesheet, but not use it to style the printing page? that's like having a car and walking to your job in the next town. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize the links using a print media query and then print, e.g.

```
@media print {
    * { background: transparent !important; color: #444 !important; text-shadow: none; }
    a, a:visited { color: #000 !important; text-decoration: none; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By "suppress" I assume you mean "style" since you can't click on links that are printed.

Use a [print stylesheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) and style the A tag to look like regular text.

Comment: I think you are right. I am new to web development and trying to figure out my terms.

Answer (score 0):

you can define all the styles for links in your `@print` css section

```
@media print {
    a { text-decoration: none; color: #000 }
}
```

Comment: This feels like a hack, though doing that does get the look I want. I was hoping to remove the links altogether, but maybe this will work instead.

Comment: nope, it's not a hack :) The `print` type is an essential part of W3C standards along with `screen` and less popular `handheld`, `tv` etc ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). And to completely remove the links you can do `a { display: none }`

Comment: I think I am understanding now. I think @media print is so you can define a specific section in your css sheet for printing. I used a whole css sheet for a print style rather than specific parts of the main css sheet.

Comment: As for the a { display: none } part, that hides the link thingies completely. I want somewhere in-between, where the text stays but the links behind the text deactivate/hide/dissapear.

Comment: the `@media print` is the same as a separate stylesheet for printing that others suggested - but putting it in your main CSS file saves you 1 HTTP request and makes your website slightly faster :) If you have the URL behind your link title you can try this to hide it `a[href]:after { content: " " !important; }`